# Stuck at being unable to print a substring no more than 4679 characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a program that does string manipulation on very large strings (around 100K). The first step in my program is to cleanup the input string so that it only contains certain characters. Here is my method for this cleanup:

```
    public static String analyzeString (String input) {
    String output = null;

    output = input.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","");
    output = output.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
    output = output.toUpperCase();
    output = output.replaceAll("[^XYZ]", "");
    return output;
}
```

When i print  my 'input' string of length 97498, it prints successfully. My output string after cleanup is of length 94788. I can print the size using output.length() but when I try to print this in Eclipse, output is empty and i can see  in eclipse output console header. Since this is not my final program, so I ignored this and proceeded to next method that does pattern matching on this 'cleaned-up' string. Here is code for pattern matching:

```
    public static List<Integer> getIntervals(String input, String regex) {
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    // Do pattern matching
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(input);

    // If match found
    while (m1.find()) {
        output.add(m1.start());
        output.add(m1.end());
    }


    return output;
}
```

Based on this program, i identify the start and end intervals of my pattern match as 12351 and 87314. I tried to print this match as output.substring(12351, 87314) and only get blank output. Numerous hit and trial runs resulted in the conclusion that biggest substring that i can print is of length 4679. If i try 4680, i again get blank input. My confusion is that if i was able to print original string (97498) length, why i couldnt print the cleaned-up string (length 94788) or the substring (length >4679). Is it due to regular expression implementation which may be causing some memory issues and my system is not able to handle that? I have 4GB installed memory.

Comment: Did you try to print from the command line? I have seen lots of issues with printing long lines to stdout in eclipse. You could also try breaking up the string into multiple lines to make it easier to digest for eclipse...

Comment: @StefanHaustein: I just tried running in console and I am getting correct output. Seems like that Eclipse is getting confused and unable to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the string to file.

Comment: Writing to the file or running the program from console works as well. Appears to be an issue with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that limit in eclipse console output is to small. You can change it in
`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Run/Debug` -> `Console`
Here you can either remove limit or increase console buffer.

---

BTW your first method seems to re traversing your string few times. Wouldn't it be better to create one regex that will match every character you want to remove and traverse input only once? In your case using only `[^XYZ]` (or `(?i)[^XYZ]` to match upper and lower case letters) should do the trick since it includes `[-+.^:,]` and `(\\r|\\n)`.

Comment: I tried changing the size from 80000 to 800000 but still could not get the output to display.

Comment: Yes, same behavior after turning off limit as well.